# ETL using apache pyspark and airflow

Tags: pyspark, airflow

We are developing ETL tool using apache pyspark and apache airflow.
Apache airflow will be used for workflow management.

1. Can apache pyspark handle huge volume of data?
2. Can i get extract,transform count from apache airflow?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Apache (Py)Spark is built for dealing with big data
2. There is no magic out-of-the-box solution for getting metrics from PySpark into Airflow

Some solutions for #2 are:

- Writing metrics from PySpark to another system (e.g. database, blob storage, ...) and reading those in a 2nd task in Airflow
- Returning the values from the PySpark jobs and pushing them into Airflow XCom

My 2c: don't process large data in Airflow itself as it's built for orchestration and not data processing. If the intermediate data becomes big, use a dedicated storage system for that (database, blob storage, etc...). XComs are stored in the Airflow metastore itself (although custom XCom backends to store data in other systems are supported since Airflow 2.0 https://www.astronomer.io/guides/custom-xcom-backends), so make sure the data isn't too big if you're storing it in the Airflow metastore.